# Order by performance problems

Tags: mysql, optimization, sql-order-by

I have an index problem with my order by statement. I have this query witch is runing fast:

```
SELECT name from members where kat = 2 order by date DESC;
```

I have a composite index on members table:

```
kat_index(kat,date);
```

Now my aplication has changed and i have added a query like this:

```
SELECT name from members where kat = 2 order by logged_in DESC, status DESC, date DESC;
```

Now the query i slow because it's using filesort. So the question is... What type of index should i add to satisfy both queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have two indexes:

```
(kat, date)
(kat, logged_in, status, date)
```

Each query will use the index that is best for that query.

Comment: @Marco, forcing indexes on simple queries makes it run **slower**, not faster.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cover both queries with one index. You must form a leftmost prefix on the composite index along with the ORDER BY clause as well.